# How to declare a Record type that accepts any type contained in a Union?

Tags: typescript

I cannot seem to find a way to express a `Record` whose values are functions that can take as an argument any type contained in a specific union type (`Option`).

This is what I've tried so far:

```
type OptionA = { type: 'a' };
type OptionB = { type: 'b' };
type Option = OptionA | OptionB;
type Handler = <T extends Option>(option: T) => boolean;
type Handlers = Partial<Record<string, Handler>>;

const handlers: Handlers = {
  a: (x: OptionA) => !!x,
  b: (x: OptionB) => !!x,
};
```

And the current error:

[image]

Any clues?

Comment: The compiler is quite right to complain about this since your typing would mean that `handlers.a?.({ type: 'b'})` is valid. Not quite sure what the solution is though...

Comment: [Please replace/supplement images of code/errors with plaintext versions.](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/285557/2887218)

Comment: Are you trying to correlate the property key of `Handlers` with the particular `Option` member accepted by the property  value?  If so, then does [this approach](https://tsplay.dev/w2P38m) work for you? I can write up an answer explaining it.  If not, please clarify what you *are* trying to do, since at face value, `(x: OptionA) => !!x` cannot "take as an argument any type contained in a specific union type", it only accepts `OptionA`, so you're not implementing what you claim to implement.  Help, I'm confused.